# Disable "Show on code map" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to disable the new "Show on code map" feature in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise?

And here is the same pop-up in **Visual Studio 2019**:
[image]

This is what it looks like in **Visual Studio 2022**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Code Map" feature can be removed using the Visual Studio Installer.

Just uncheck these two features and click "Modify":
[image]

See the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/install-architecture-tools?view=vs-2022) for more information.